# How to create consistent spacing between html elements?

Tags: html, css, layout, user-experience

I am about to start a large, design oriented website that just has to be pixel perfect and as good as possible.

The problem is how to keep consistent spacing between elements in a container like this:

[image: Padding explanation]

Currently I create all containers with
`padding: 40px 40px 30px` and every element with `margin-bottom: 10px;`

This solves the problem nicely, but every element, including headings, has to have exactly 10 pixels below itself and zero pixels above itself.

Currently I also use https://github.com/kiskadigitalmedia/kiskabricks_wedgecss (div with set height) to create additional vertical whitespace if the design calls for it. Like here:

[image]

This is the code for the above example:

```
<div class="card">
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <p>Paragraph text</p>
    <div class="wedge-2x">
    <a class="btn">Button</a>
</div>
```

Does this approach make sense? Is there any better way to guarantee consistent spacing of elements inside a container? Any input appreciated.

Comment: At one point you say "this solves the problem nicely", but you don't say what the remaining problems are. Do any of the lines of text wordwrap? Are you worried that changing fonts may cause additional issues?

Comment: One thing that bothers me is that you can't have 30px top-margin on heading1. This way you have to use a lot of those wedges to create desired whitespace. This is my main concern with this technique

Comment: Sorry, then I don't seem to grasp the problem. You say "every element, including headings, has to have exactly 10 pixels below itself and zero pixels above itself." So you're doing it right. Right? And there is padding on the container, which already solves the problem of the space above the heading?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
<div class="card">
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <p>Paragraph text</p>
    <a class="btn">Button</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.card {
    padding: 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1, p {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.btn {
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Problem is what if you have just a button in a card? Than we would have 60px at the top. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/2334eaop/

Comment: Yea, the no-space class is one idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you want for example a 10 pixels margin above & below your elements, an option could be something like this. All the elements inside the `class="card"` will be affected by the same margins.

```
.card{
padding: 40px;
}

.card h1, .card p, .card .wedge-2x, .card a{
margin: 30px 0px;
}
```

Comment: Nice. That's what I am doing now ;-) Not sure if adding top margin is a good idea

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much flexibility you want to have.
your solution looks like a good start. maybe try and use siblings selectors too?

so in scss you'd have something like:

```
.card {
    padding: 40px;
    h1 ~ p,
    h1 ~ a { margin-top: 10px; }
}
```

Or use `+` instead of `~` if you want a more specific HTML structure.

Or you could rewrite this using `margin-top` for all elements except for the first one, by using `:first-child { ... }`